# Obscure movie about orphans forced to work in mill/factory

Tags: identify-this-movie

This movie has bugged me for years, I watched it on television a couple times (perhaps Disney channel but perhaps HBO) in the very early 90's. I was a young child and it sort of disturbed me.

I believe it was centered around orphan children, working in a mill or clothing factory. They were mixing clothes in large vats with big wooden spoons? Anyway at one point a child falls into one of the vats and I think drowns. Later I vaguely remember two orphans snuck away, are in some dark place (perhaps mounds of coal near a boiler) talking about escaping or trying to escape.

I believe it was set in the Victorian or industrial era.

Comment: I am looking for this movie as well!! I'm pretty sure it was disney. Did you ever find it?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like [The Wolves of Willoughby Chase](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096459/). The scenes in the workhouse were towards the end of the movie. In the beginning of the movie, the children were still living at their parents' house under the care of a governess, who sends them to the workhouse when she receives news that the parents are dead. At the end we learn that:

> The parents aren't dead; they were shipwrecked and marooned on an island.